# is it correct to say "Can my spouse be covered under my health insurance?"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

In an email I want to ask about health insurance of my spouse by my company. What is the correct way to ask about it?

Is it grammatically correct to say *under my health insurance* in the following question:

> Can my spouse be covered under my health insurance?

Comment: Note that "Can my spouse be covered under my health insurance?" is very different from "Is my spouse covered under my health insurance?" One is speaking about a possible policy (to be agreed), whereas one is speaking about an existing one.

Comment: Idiomatically, the most common preposition is *covered **by** your insurance*, but *covered **under** your insurance* is [far from unknown.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=covered+under+your+insurance%2Ccovered+by+your+insurance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccovered%20under%20your%20insurance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccovered%20by%20your%20insurance%3B%2Cc0) I wouldn't say this is a matter of one being "grammatically correct" though.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. Unlike the previous comment, I find *under* to be more common than *by*. At least here in Canada. But both versions are fine.